# Node not moving

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to throw a node around the screen, I've taken the below code but nothing actually happens.

When the scene loads the node spawns in the middle of the screen then drops to the bottom.

The code was taken from elsewhere in the site and granted it was a bit old so I'm assuming I'm missing something?

```
var sprite: SKSpriteNode!
var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
var touching: Bool = false

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: sprite.size)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0)
    self.addChild(sprite)
}

 func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if sprite.frame.contains(location) {
            touchPoint = location
            touching = true
        }
    }
}

 func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        touchPoint = location
    }
}

 func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    touching = false
}

 func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    touching = false
}

func update(currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if touching {
        let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/60.0
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-sprite.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-sprite.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        sprite.physicsBody!.velocity = velocity
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `touchesMoved` should be updating the position of `sprite`

Comment: How though? sorry im new to coding and still trying to learn it all.

Comment: @Mick Don't try to grab bits of code from here and expect them to work. Find a good beginner's Sprite-kit tutorial, follow it and make sure you understand *every* line of code. I'd recommend Ray Wenderlich's site, but others are available.  Are you new to any form of coding, or new to Swift, or new to SK? P.s. Your sprite is probably falling off the screen due to gravity.

Comment: the node isnt falling off the screen, thats not the problem. the problem is that the node is sitting at the bottom of the screen and is immovable. At the very least i should be able to move the node around but i cant even do that.

Comment: @Mick - the node isn't falling off the screen due to the 'self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)' which creates a body around the screen that the sprite can't move through.

Comment: With all due respect, @SteveIves, finding a good beginners tutorial is an impossible mission for a beginner, even if there were good ones available. I don't believe there are, but that's (actually) besides the point, because beginners aren't able to ascertain which is a good tutorial.

Comment: Add the following lines to touchesBegan after 'let location...' : 'print("Touched \(location)"' and 'print("Sprite location is \(sprite.position)")'

Comment: Let's take, for example, your write ups on Sprite Kit physics steps, procedures and mechanics of creation and articulation. They look dry and foreboding to the uninformed. But they're actually a rare thing, in that they're the bare list of that which is required, isolated from the preening, posturing and posing prevalent in what might otherwise look like a good tutorial. Your short lists provide more insight and are worth more than ANY existing tutorials on SpriteKit physics. But how would a beginner recognise that fact?

Comment: @Confused this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/94649/sprite-kit-kids-swift is so simple that if someone can't follow it, then maybe this sort of programming is not for them - some people just cannot get their head around coding. An alternative is this one: https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners which doesn't use physics.

Comment: Simple != good.

Comment: As to not getting their head around coding, that's an entirely different problem, and part of the problem with tutorials. I don't see the need for tutorials if you've got your head around coding, and I don't see how tutorials can help someone get their head around programming. I don't really see the benefit of tutorials, other than to the tutor.

Comment: Someone like Matt Neuberg does an amazing job of both introducing programming and the way it works within a world of massive frameworks. And that's the most important thing, to blend an understanding of how programming actually works with how frameworks then abuse how it works and ignore all the principles and ideals of any given language and/or programming paradigm. Learning programming purely won't help much with how it actually works within any given real world framework, and SpriteKit is a very good example of this kind of real world clusterfuck. Not struct or POP based, at all. Yet Swift?

Comment: And then we come back to the problems of tutorials, how are they going to help understand a framework of the complexity and multi-paradigm "design" and "inspiration" that is the mess of SpriteKit? They can't. They can only show one way of doing one thing. Tutorials always fail on theory, rarely do good explanations and are not generally applicable. They're a refined example of, as I say, one activity, in one way. Which is next to useless. Your lists of what's required to achieve physics, that's the better way to introduce the roles and rules of doing any given task inside something like SK.

Comment: This guy, the OP, obviously has some clues. He's forcibly created an SKSpriteNode outside the didMoveTo function, rightly or wrongly, and then done a bunch of other things that demonstrate he's got a basic understanding of how SpriteKit is structured to work. So he's in need of that kind of list that only someone with your insights and wisdom can provide as a checklist for how to think about and configure Sprites and then animate them. I can't be the first to tell you this; you're good at breaking down tasks into their connected and interleaved responsibilities, and communicating it.

Comment: Just one more thing, I'm of the opinion that anyone can be helped to get their head around coding. It's just the declaration and defining of things and commands, and then issuing commands upon things. The arbitrary and (often needless) obtuse complexity of syntax is why its called code. But it's fundamentally not more than creating something and then telling it what to do.